# Proving the identity $\int_\alpha^\beta | f(t) | dt \leq \sqrt{\beta - \alpha} \cdot || f ||$

Tags: fourier-analysis

For my Fourier analysis class, we have to prove this identity for piecewise continuous $f$ on an interval $(\alpha,\beta)$:

$$\int_\alpha^\beta | f(t) | dt \leq \sqrt{\beta - \alpha}  \cdot || f ||$$

We are advised to make use of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for inner products (stated as $| \left \langle f,g \right \rangle | \leq ||f|| \cdot ||g||$) and the fact $f = f \cdot 1$.

Initially, working with $g(t)=1$ suffices to yield the following (skipping over a few formalities of the definition and calculation of inner product and norm for brevity's sake):

$$| \left \langle f,1 \right \rangle | = \left |  \int_\alpha^\beta f(t) dt \right |$$

$$||1|| = \int_\alpha^\beta dt = \sqrt{\beta - \alpha}$$

Thus, so far by my calculations and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,

$$| \left \langle f,1 \right \rangle | = \left |  \int_\alpha^\beta f(t) dt \right | \leq \sqrt{\beta - \alpha} \cdot ||f|| = ||f|| \cdot ||1||$$

Of course, this isn't quite the identity we want; that is, to reiterate

$$\int_\alpha^\beta | f(t) | dt \leq \sqrt{\beta - \alpha} \cdot || f ||$$

(The difference being that the absolute value needs to be moved into the integral.)

I imagine I need to make use of the identity

$$\left |  \int_\alpha^\beta f(t) dt \right | \leq \int_\alpha^\beta | f(t) | dt$$

yet it's probably a little more nuanced than just applying it directly. (We'd essentially have a case of where we're saying $1 \leq 2$ and $1 \leq 4$ - doesn't mean $4 \leq 2$. In this case, $1$ being the absolute value of the integral, $2$ being the root and norm, and $4$ being the integral of the absolute value, as an oversimplification of why I don't think directly applying that identity would work.)

Does anyone have an idea of where to proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: What ? By Cauchy-Schwartz, $$\left<|f|,1\right>\leq \sqrt{\beta -\alpha }\|f\|.$$ Done !

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, okay. I hadn't considered that, but it seems to work out; a few small nuances to work around, but I figured out how to handle them as I was originally about to comment on that (thus why you've might've gotten notified for some things that got deleted).

Thanks for the help; sorry for being dumb. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the question is still open and I can't accept a comment as an answer:

The solution followed from $⟨|f|,1⟩≤\sqrt{β−α}∥f∥$